# How to embed MacRuby in your app from XCode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, macruby

I'm trying to "deploy" a MacRuby 0.10 app that has MacRuby embedded so that I can distribute my app to users without MacRuby installed. I can't seem to figure out how to deploy an app like this from XCode 4. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Embedding MacRuby

After following the steps found in [this article](http://redwoodapp.posterous.com/macruby-and-xcode-4-build-a-self-contained-ma) I realized that I needed to **add an additional build target**. There are other steps in that article that you will need to follow. I had already done them, so I didn't need to.

#### Archiving an app with spaces in the name

I also ran across an issue since the name of my app had a space in it. If your app name has a space, you will need to create a `Custom Archive Name` that doesn't include spaces. To create a `Custom Archive Name`:

1. Edit the Deployment Scheme
2. Click on the Archive tab
3. Then specify an Archive Name that doesn't have spaces in it.

[image: Specify a Custom Archive Name]

Now I'm able to embed MacRuby when I "archive" my app in order to distribute it to my co-workers.